# gcc, width of long int on different architectures

Tags: gcc, g++, 64-bit, long-integer

On 64-bit architectures, `long int`, according to gcc is at least an `int64_t`. On 32-bit, `long int` is at least `int32_t`. With Microsoft compilers, `long` is always an `int32_t`, regardless of 32/64-bit. Is there any way to:

1. Force gcc to treat long as a int64_t, on 32bit? (for ease of testing)
2. Force gcc to treat long as a int32_t on 64bit? (for compliance with MS's compiler).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don't do this - use standard types such as `int32_t`, `uint32_t`, `int64_t`, `uint64_t`, etc from `<stdint.h>` rather than trying to make assumptions about naked types such as `long int` or trying to bend the compiler to your will.

Note: The 64-bit model for any given platform (e.g. LP64 for most *nix platforms, Mac OS X, etc) is a given, so even if you could convince the compiler to use a different 64-bit model you would probably break any calls to system code, libraries, etc.

Comment: See my comment to Goz's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is why its generally much easier to use a set of typedefs that are defined per platform.  It will really save you a lot of hassle when compiling on random-platform-with-random-compiler-47.4

Comment: I use boost's cstdint in all my projects. I can't force other members of my team, or library authors to do the same. Forcing it at the compiler level (if at all possible) seems safer.

Comment: @John: if your team members are writing fragile/unsafe/non-portable code then you need to fix them and/or their code.