# Actual Value of Machine-"Specifics" in C

Tags: c

I have been reading the [C++ Primer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), due to all the claims of how usable the language has become because of C++11. The book is probably ok, but it still leaves me wondering every few pages about what the code really does. A a result I end up [googling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244311/gcc-width-of-long-int-on-different-architectures/4244405#4244405) [lots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254051/the-difference-of-int8-t-int-least8-t-and-int-fast8-t/5254157#5254157) [and](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54342) [lots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656241/how-to-print-uint128-t-number-using-gcc) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016861/null-pointer-in-c-and-c) [stuff](http://c-faq.com/null/) [..](http://c-faq.com/struct/align.esr.html) only to eventually end up with something along the lines of that bit is "machine specific" or "implementation defined", etc.

I realize what that means, and how portable code is important.

Yet I do wonder, what are the actual values for these specifics for "run-of-the-mill" 64bit x86 PCs? Since GCC, Visual Studio, etc. don't actually ask about what to do in all these cases, but just compile the code (and it works!), there seems to be some sane set of defaults for targeting desktops.

Is there a document that covers these details (in a for non-compiler-writers understandable way, like the pages that I linked to)?

Comment: Why do you read "C++ Primer" if you want to learn C?

Answer (score 1):

Most Unix or Linux systems you can login and issue the command

locate limits.h

and it will find a number of include files that list the "limits" for values used by the compiler.  Many of the limits files in the Linux kernel code are architecture specific, which is your especial interest

Comment: Yes, I already did that. However that only leads to more questions since it partly uses compiler intrinsics (see the 3rd link) and doesn't explain things like alignment, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, portability is difficult to obtain 100%. I've been programming for 30 years and have never seen anything but simple programs that are 100% portable. Given the PC is ubiquitous, I don't think you should concern yourself with portability over functionality. Hence, all the references you find to "implementation defined".

In a perfect world, programs would be portable. In the real world, OS makers add features to compete with other OS makers and even themselves (Win 95, 98, 2000, XP, 7, Vista) (and Linux distros have differences). As a result, being portable -- IN MY EXPERIENCE -- means a trade-off you're not willing to make: too slow, too bulky, too much development time, too much testing, etc. If you seek portability, you need to ask why and is it worth it. Even if you decide to do so, you will find yourself adding compile-time options based on your environment and may end up with entire files that are specific and non-portable.

When I write code for an Atmel Mega16 I don't consider whether I'm going to port that code. In this case, you don't have the luxury of infinite CPU cycles and boundless memory to consider a portable solution -- we're trying to squeeze all the juice out of a little micro.

Likewise, it's often the case you need to optimize routines in assembler in order to gain back CPU cycles for more features. (Like a DSP running a DFT -- it's ok in C when you first ship it, but eventually you need to reduce that to ASM to get back a pile of CPU cycles for 23 more features your boss wants you to add by tomorrow morning. Portability be damned.)

So, yes, much is implementation specific. In the PC world you have a little more luxury, but if you're writing code that interfaces with hardware you're often forced to create non-portable code. I could go on and on about this, but I have a loop that needs optimizing...