# How to force long to be 4 byte

Tags: c++, arrays, int, long-integer, sizeof

I have a problem. When I compile my project I have `sizof(long int) = 8` and `sizof(int) = 4`. However, I need `sizeof(long int)` to be 4 as well. Is there a way to do that? 
The problem is that I have a lot of huge int arrays and need to asign them to long int arrays. It would result in a lot of time if I cast all arrays (specifically that means, casting each entry of the arrays).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244311/gcc-width-of-long-int-on-different-architectures

Comment: delete all `long` from `long int`, or replace/redefine `long int` with `int32_t`

Comment: Have you tried, or do you only assume it will be slow? The speed is almost certainly memory bandwidth-bound.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't force the built-in `long int` type to be 4 bytes long on LP64 platforms (or stranger platforms, for that matter).

However, you can use the types in `<stdint.h>` to guarantee the exact size of your variables.

In your case you'll want either `int32_t` or `uint32_t` as your type, depending on whether you require/want a sign bit.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to tell the compiler the platform you are targeting or use compiler specific commands to tell the compiler the size of your variables.

Another method is to use a macro and define it based on your platform:

```
#if PLATFORM_USES_8_BYTE_LONG
#define MY_LONG_INT int32_t
#else
#define MY_LONG_INT long int
#endif
```

The preferred method is to set up you compiler for the target architecture.  Many compilers have a large list of predefined architectures to choose from.